# Using Selenium without java runtime

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way I can use selenium without having to install java runtime on my remote machine?(the machine where the browser is)

The machine that automates the process( where the tests run will have java) but the remote machine where the browser is does not have java. is it possible? and if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Launch4j for embedding JRE into your java application package.

**Useful links**:
1. [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
2. [A SO post for how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j/7582064#7582064)
3. [Another SO answer which describes how to do it on different OSes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13876466/1335594)

Comment: When Selenium NuGet package is installed for .NET app, I never notice Java being installed. Does Selenium for .NET work without Java?