# Bundle JRE with IZPACK installer

Tags: java, installation, izpack, launch4j, izpanel

I have created an installer using IZPACK 4.3.5
Currently it is making use of the system installed JRE/JVM. 
i want to ship/bundle the JRE with the installer so that we can run the installer even the end user doesn't have any JRE installed in his machine.

Could you please give me suggestions/idea to achieve this in izpack?

Comment: I have created installer using izpack 4.3.5. I am shipping/exporting jvm with my install.jar to the end user.but how can i make sure that my installer should work with the shipping/exporting jvm? following is the folder structure

how can i set the path for jvm if i unzip the same structure in the end user working folder?

       my installer (main folder)  with in this i have  jvm folder and another is my installar.jar

Comment: I suppose, it's not a task for IzPack, but for something, that call IzPAck itself and then makes something to pack this intaller else where. As for me, we achieved it with Gradle script, which is compiling and building our projects, then call IzPack to create installer and then it bundles this installer together with start scripts and documentation into Zip-archive

Comment: I found this answer helpful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13876466/1503780