# How to package and deploy Scala applications with a JRE and Scala Library?

Tags: scala, packaging, auto-update, sbt-native-packager

I'm about to start creating a simple client application that needs to be fully self contained and super easy to install. I was looking around at what packaging / deployment solutions there are for Scala. The requirements at this stage is that it must contain its own JRE (rather than relying on the system one) and be really easy to install (native installers/scripts or a zip). At some point it will also need to auto-update but I can do this manually unless there is a better solution.

I came across SBT Native Packager. This looks really cool and seems to give me most of the things I want. However I couldn't see an obvious way to include a JRE though.

What is the best way to package and deploy Scala applications with a JRE and Scala Library? Can this solution also cater for in place upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JDKPackagerPlugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/jdkpackager.html). SBT Native Packager provides a nice API for this jdk tool. Requirement is java8 on your build system.

JDKPackager provides outputs for almost all major OS. However you can only build native package types on the respective native OS.

Comment: Ah ok I did see that but I thought it was something different. I didn't realise it could also generate native package types as well. I'll look into this and report back on how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

As scala is compiled to java bytecode anyway you could search for a java solution.
Like this one:
[How to deliver my Java application with a particular JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045719/how-to-deliver-my-java-application-with-a-particular-jre)